# Kubernetes add Toleration from CLI

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I'm using the Oracle Cloud Infrastructure with Kubernetes and Docker. I've got the following pod:

```
$ kubectl describe pod $podname -n $namespace
Events:
  Type     Reason            Age   From               Message
  ----     ------            ----  ----               -------
  Warning  FailedScheduling  19m   default-scheduler  0/1 nodes are available: 1 node(s) had taint {nvidia.com/gpu: }, that the pod didn't tolerate.
  Warning  FailedScheduling  18m   default-scheduler  0/1 nodes are available: 1 node(s) had taint {nvidia.com/gpu: }, that the pod didn't tolerate.
```

I want to add a toleration to this pod - is there a command to do so, without creating the pod config yaml file (as this pod is created by some other systems that I don't want to edit. I just want to add the toleration to resolve this issue.

Thanks.

====================

`gpu-config.yaml`

```yaml
apiVersion: v1 # What version of the Kubernetes API to use
kind: Pod      # What kind of object you want to create
metadata:      # Data that helps uniquely identify the object, including a name, string, UID and optional namespace
  name: nvidia-gpu-workload
spec:          # What state you desire for the object, differs for every type of Kubernetes object.
  restartPolicy: OnFailure
  containers:
    - name: cuda-vector-add
      image: k8s.gcr/io/cuda-vector-add:v0.1
      resources:
        limits:
          nvidia.com/gpu: 1
  tolerations:
  - key: "nvidia.com/gpu"
    operator: "Equal"
    effect: "NoSchedule"
```

```sh
# Update command
$ kubectl create -f ./gpu-config.yaml
# All this seems to do is create a pod by the name of nvidia-gpu-workload-v2, and it doesn't add these configurations to the pod that I require.
```

Just to note that this issue is occurring on a pod called hook-image-awaiter-5tq5 and I don't think I should re-create that pod with a different config as it seems to be configured by part of the system.

Comment: Usually Pods are dynamically created and destroyed by Deployments or StatefulSets, and for the most part you can't edit them once they're created.  I'd recommend editing the YAML (or providing a setting to something like a Helm chart), committing the change to source control, and redeploying.

Comment: @DavidMaze Thanks for the response. I've tried editing the YAML file for the pod configuration after posting this and it doesn't seem to work. Will edit the original post to include it. Would you be able to try to point out any errors that I've made?

Comment: Also the YAML file seems to create a new Kubernetes pod, and doesn't resolve the error that I'm having - the error seems to be a scheduling error with the hook image awaiter on the Oracle Cloud Infrastructure when created using the Oracle Kubernetes Engine.